# In Android, Is there a way to load google-services.json from a REST API rather than copying to project?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to load google-services.json from a REST API rather than copying it to the project? this is needed because we need to generate some resources dynamically. Is my approach wrong, if so, please suggest a better way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation regarding [The Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin):

> The `google-services` plugin has two main functions:
>
> 1. Process the google-services.json file and produce Android resources that can be used in your application's code.
> 2. Add dependencies for basic libraries required for the services you have enabled. This step requires that you apply the Google Services Gradle plugin in your app/build.gradle file, like so:
>    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

And to answer your question:

> Is there a way to load google-services.json from an API rather than copying it to the project?

No, you cannot. You have to explicitly add the file to the project's `app` directory. Alternatively, you can use product flavors when you have to use more complicated directory structures:

```
// free and paid are product flavors.
app/
    google-services.json
    src/dogfood/paid/google-services.json
    src/release/free/google-services.json
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because the initialisation of Google libraries is internal and it expects to read client information from this file.

Comment: Is there a document of some sort that I can read about? couldn't find by googling

Comment: Firebase SDK doesn't have any initialize mechanism where you can provide all this data